# Dr. Memory: are these lines really causing of memory leaks?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, destructor, dr-memory

I have the following code:

```
class Node {
    public:
        int data;
        Node* parent;
        std::unique_ptr<Node> left;
        std::unique_ptr<Node> right;
    public:       
        explicit Node(int d) : data(d),
                               parent(nullptr),
                               left(nullptr),
                               right(nullptr) { }
        /*
            Some functions
        */                  
};

class dt {
    private:            
        Node* root;
    private:        
        void add_helper(Node* parent, Node* node); 
        /*
                Some helper functions
        */      
    public:
        dt() : root(nullptr) {}
        ~dt() {
            delete root;
        } 
        /*
                Some functions
        */       
        void add(int data);        
};


void dt::add(int data) {
    if(!root) {
        root = new Node(data); // 1: memory leak
        return;
    }   
    Node* node = new Node(data); // 2: memory leak
    add_helper(root, node);
}
```

When I scanning this code for memory leaks **Dr. Memory** shows errors on the lines mentioned in the comments above. But are they really memory leaks? **dt** has destructor where the **root** pointer is deleting. When the destructor will start to delete the **root** node it will go recursively and will delete all his children. Or there is something else that happens?

Comment: Don't see a memory leak, but I definitely see massive memory corruption, and pretty much a guaranteed crash, if you ever attempt to actually delete a root node of a tree with at least a couple of levels of hierarchy. I strongly suspect that the rest of the code, which is not shown, never actually attempts to delete an entire tree.

Comment: ... what @SamVarshavchik said and please make it a [mcve] so we can do the same analysis.

Comment: Why does the Node destructor delete its parent?  Usually the pattern is for each node to delete its children (which in your case happens via std::unique_ptr's dtor, which is fine)

Comment: Jeremy Friesner- Good point, will examine this case.

Comment: Ted Lyngmo - Agree will post the minimal working example.

Comment: Sam Varshavchik - Why a corruption could happen? Could you please describe a bit more detailed?

Comment: @ՎարդանԳրիգորյան When you post the [mcve] someone will give you details.

Comment: Ted Lyngmo - I'm working on it. The codes are pretty big.

Comment: @ՎարդանԳրիգորյան That's ok, take your time. In the future, be prepared to get the same requirement so start by compressing your question down to code ready to be copied, compiled and analysed without *any* blanks to fill in.

Comment: Your `class dt` violates the Rule of Five, which is bound to cause problems.  More of the double-delete variety than the leak variety.

Comment: Ben Voigt- Agreed. Collision related to Rule of Five could be solved by declaring root weak_ptr or shared_ptr, but weak ptr is more preferable to avoid cycling problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> are these lines really causing of memory leaks?

The memory allocated on line `Node* node = new Node(data)` is potentially leaked. At least the example doesn't show where the pointer would be deleted. The ownership could potentially be transferred within `add_helper`, but that has been excluded from the example.

I'm not familiar with Dr. Memory, but I would hypothesise that it reports where the leaked memory was allocated; not where it was leaked.

---

Furthermore, if you make a copy of a `dt` instance, the behaviour of the program will be undefined because both the original and the copy will attempt to delete the copied pointer.

To fix both the potential memory leak, and the potential UB, use unique pointer. Just like you used with `Node`.

> I can't use unqiue_ptr for root because there are multiple pointers to the same Node.

By doing `delete root;` in the destructor, your class is assuming unique ownership of the pointer. If that assumption is correct, then there is no problem with using a unique pointer. If the assumption is incorrect, then the destructor probably leads to undefined behaviour. Using that instead of a unique pointer is not a solution. You may need to use a shared pointer instead.

Lastly, unless your tree is balanced, the implicit recursive destructor has linearly increasing worst case recursion depth, which can easily cause a stack overflow. You should either balance the tree (for example using red-back or AVL augmentations) or use an iterative algorithm to destroy the children.

Comment: But when root is null then it returns from the function without executing line: Node* node = new Node(data). As for pointer, I can't use unqiue_ptr for root because there are multiple pointers to the same Node.

Comment: eerorika, Ok thanks. You are right, ownership transfers into add_helper. Will post mre to be mo clear.

Comment: eerorika- Actually the part of codes that are shown here from my implementation of AVL tree.

Comment: @ՎարդանԳրիգորյան ah. Then you don't need to worry about the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: eerorika - Thanks for the detailed answer. I suppose weak_ptr would be more preferable in this particular case to avoid cycling problems. Don't you think so?

Comment: @ՎարդանԳրիգորյան Sure, if you have a cycle, then a weak pointer at some point will prevent the ownership from becoming cyclical.